# How to establish a happens-before relationship between a request handling thread and a SocketChannel selector thread?

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, nio, happens-before

Consider a request-response protocol.

We spawn a thread to perform a `select()` loop for reads and writes on an accepted non-blocking `SocketChannel`. That might look something like

```
while (!isStopped()) {
    selector.select();
    Iterator<SelectionKey> selectedKeys = selector.selectedKeys().iterator();

    while (selectedKeys.hasNext()) {
        SelectionKey selectedKey = selectedKeys.next();
        selectedKeys.remove();
        Context context = (Context) selectedKey.attachment();
        if (selectedKey.isReadable()) {
            context.readRequest();
        } else /* if (selectedKey.isWritable()) */ {
            context.writeResponse();
        }
    }
}
```

where `Context` is just a container for the corresponding `SocketChannel`, a buffer and logic to read into it and write from it. The `readRequest` might look like

```
public void readRequest() {
    // read all content
    socketChannel.read(requestBuffer);
    // not interested anymore
    selectionKey.interestOps(0);
    executorService.submit(() -> {
        // handle request with request buffer and prepare response
        responseBuffer.put(/* some response content */); // or set fields of some bean that will be serialized

        // notify selector, ready to write
        selectionKey.interestOps(SelectionKey.OP_WRITE);
        selectionKey.selector().wakeup(); // worried about this
    });
}
```

In other words, we read from the socket channel, populate some buffer and hand off the handling to some other thread. That thread does the handling and prepares a response which it stores in a response buffer. It then notifies the selector that it wants to write and wakes it up.

The Javadoc for [`Selector#wakeup()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/channels/Selector.html#wakeup--) doesn't mention any happens-before relationship so I'm worried the selector thread might see the response buffer (or some intermediate object) in an inconsistent state.

Is that a possible scenario? If it is, what's the correct way to hand off a response to be written to a `SocketChannel` by a `Selector` loop thread? (Publishing the response through some `volatile` field? Using a `SelectionKey` attachment? Some other form of synchronization?)

Comment: This appears to be a dupe of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28754275/149138) which also has no good answer. My answer would probably be that there is, in practice, a happens-before relationship between the `wakeup()` on one thread and the `select()` call on another thread which receives the wakeup. That's for two practical reasons: for it to work in any other way would make the API pretty useless and the internal mechanics of a typical implementation are going to involve the same types of atomic and lock primitives that enforce this happens before order. I think it's a doc defect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation on `Selector`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/channels/Selector.html) says the following:

> The selection operations synchronize on the selector itself, on the key set, and on the selected-key set, in that order.

The [*happens-before* relation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html#MemoryVisibility) is defined in the [Java Language Specification, Chapter 17](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4.5), as including the *synchronizes-with* relation.

Even so, you should synchronize properly on the attached object.  That's your object, it's your duty.  Assuming only your code writes to `responseBuffer` in the executor's thread, and only the selector thread reads from it *after* you say you're interested on write availability, you have enough synchronization.

What may surprise you is that you're getting that synchronization from `interestOps(...)`, even before `wakeup()`.

---

From my experience, if you have a hard time trying to achieve proper synchronization through library utilities (in this case, a selector), you'd better synchronize your object yourself, e.g. with the `synchronize` statement on the object itself, a `ReentrantLock`, some other common synchronization object you use on your object's operations, etc.  You lose a tiny bit of performance (actually, insignificant in most cases, assuming you don't block within the guarded section) to keep calm.

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, you don't need to notify the selector about wanting to write. You just write. Only in the case where the write returned zero does the selector or its thread need to be involved.

Secondly, the happens-before relationship occurs as a result of the selector's three levels of synchronization, provided you also do a synchronization, as below.

Your code may *block* in the `interestOps()` call if the selector is currently selecting. The possibility is not excluded by the Javadoc. You need to do the operations in the right order:

1. Wakeup.
2. Synchronize on the selector.
3. Call `interestOps()`.

The combination of (2) and the selector's own internal synchronizations establishes any necessary happens-before relationships.

Comment: What do you mean by _currently selecting_? As long the `select()` method call hasn't yet returned (while it's blocked or while it's preparing all its sets)?I wasn't able to reproduce blocking in `interestOps(..)` while the selector thread was blocked in `select()`.

Comment: Your suggested order would add the happens-before through `synchronized(selector)`. I assume you suggest this because _The selection operations synchronize on the selector itself, on the key set, and on the selected-key set, in that order._ Correct? Does `select` release the lock on its `Selector` if it goes into a blocking state? Is that documented anywhere or are we meant to assume? What happens if the `select` thread is able to re-invoke `select` between 1 and 2.

Comment: 'Currently selecting' means the same as 'hasn't yet returned from `select()`'. The selector doesn't release those three locks when it blocks: it can't, as they are synchronizations, so it follows from the text you quoted. If it re-invokes `select()` between 1 and 2, 2 will wait until `select()` returns next.

Comment: Concerning _2 will wait until select() returns next_, that seems just as undesirable as `interestOps` being blocked, with an admittedly smaller chance of occurring, though I have yet to see `interestOps` block. Could we resolve this by setting some flag (establishing the happens-before), waking up the selector, and letting its thread do the write and modifying the interest set?

Comment: You can resolve it by doing a very short sleep if `select()` returns zero, to ensure that (2) is entered before `select()` runs again. You don't need it if `select()` returns non-zero, as it that case it will be traversing the selected-key set, processing ready keys, accepting, reading, etc.

Comment: There's not much harm in using the selector to write.  There is harm in writing from multiple threads, as one thread might initiate writing while other threads will block waiting for the first to finish.

Comment: @acelent The 'harm' in using the selector to write is added latency, and the harm you do mention is not only non-existent but nonsensical. Writes don't block in non-blocking mode, and in any case you wouldn't be writing to the same channel from multiple threads.

Comment: *"and in any case you wouldn't be writing to the same channel from multiple threads."* – Thanks for making this clear.  Otherwise, there is harm, more so regarding order.

Comment: As for the nonsensical part, unfortunately it's the [documentation's fault](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/nio/channels/SocketChannel.html#write-java.nio.ByteBuffer-).  I agree with you that, in practice, writes from multiple threads on non-blocking sockets don't block each other, but the documentation is not specific about this, and it says a thread will block waiting for a write to finish.

Comment: I just found out that [the code](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk9/jdk9/jdk/file/65464a307408/src/java.base/share/classes/sun/nio/ch/SocketChannelImpl.java#l459) actually uses a lock.  Perhaps that's why it's documented like that, although it should probably not be noticeable in most cases for non-blocking sockets.

Comment: @acelent I have no idea what documentation deficiency you are talking about. It is certainly specified that writes don't block in non-blocking mode. It also blindingly obvious. I also don't understand why it needs to be 'made clear' that no sane application would attempt writing to a socket from multiple threads. This also seems obvious. There certainly is harm in doing that, regardless of how you implement it. It isn't a deficiency of NIO, or its documentation, or this answer.

Comment: At the very least, it has a lock in Java itself, you have to give in to that.  As for the sanity of not using multiple threads to write simultaneously, there's plenty examples of insane approaches in questions (and even some answers) all over [so].  As for anything being "obvious", that's a matter of opinion.

Comment: @acelent There is no evidence *in this question* about writing to the same channel from multiple threads. That is a matter you introduced yourself, and it remains unjustified. What other questions may or may not contain is irrelevant.